# Embedded help topics in a phonegap app

Tags: backbone.js, cordova

I'm using Cordova / Phonegap for a mobile application, along with backbone.js for MV* support. This app is likely to be used where there is no internet connectivity for large periods of time, so I'd like to bundle some help files along with the app -- so that they can be used offline.

Right now I just have the beginnings of a single Backbone View to display help topics:

```
var HelpView    = require('app/views/HelpView'),
    helpView    = new HelpView();

return Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "":             "home",     // (top level)
        "help":         "help",    // #help
        //etc.
    },
    help: function () {
        helpView.delegateEvents();
        slider.slidePage(helpView.$el);
    },
    // etc.
```

But this kind of feels like I'm reinventing the wheel. Are there any sorts of best practices / frameworks for help support out there?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't heard of a "standard" way of doing this, I'd say go ahead. :)

Comment: Okay. I'll update this question with what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I hadn't followed up here with what we ended up doing. Which is, well, not really a separate help system.

We ended up using a **help walkthrough system** instead. A bit simpler, but mobile apps should be designed to be intuitive enough to work through with just a basic orientation. There are several UX patterns out there for implementing walkthroughs ([Here are some](http://www.mobile-patterns.com/walkthroughs)) -- and several javascript frameworks out there as well:

- Bootstro.js: http://clu3.github.io/bootstro.js/
- Bootstrap Tour: http://github.com/Gild/bootstrap-tour
- Chardin.js: http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/
- Hopscotch.js: https://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/
- Intro.js: http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/
- Joyride: http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

I had originally started with Joyride, but there were some CSS class collisions that were causing headaches. We ended up with hopscotch.js, which is maintained by LinkedIn and also offers support for localizations of the walkthrough text (nice!).